# Receiving "Connection Refused" on NodeJS app for external connections on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, express, network-programming

I'm receiving a "Connection Refused" error when attempting to connect to my NodeJS server running a REST API. My environment is Windows 10.

I've tried numerous only solution, but to no avail.

- curl & postman works with localhost, but not external
- nstat shows listening on 0.0.0.0:8143
- Just testing the **get** at the moment, not post
- Opened port on windows firewall
- NGrok works (although I've read production use is not recommended)
- using the following for external: http://xxx:8143/run/

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
var cors = require('cors')

let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan')
let router = require('./routes/run.route');


// connection configure ---
const dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const dbName = 'rundata';

const Mongoose = require("mongoose");
Mongoose.connect(`${dbURI}/${dbName}`);


// app configure
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended" : false }));
app.use("/", router);
app.use(logger('dev', {skip: function(req, res) { return true; }}));

app.listen('8143','0.0.0.0',()=>{
    console.log("server is listening on 8143 port");
})
```

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Run = require("../schemas/run.model");

router.route("/run")
    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        
        let data = req.body;
        data.ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.socket.remoteAddress || null;
        
        let query = {'runId': req.body.runId}
        
        Run.findOneAndUpdate(query, data, {upsert: true}, function(err) {
            res.json(err ?
                {"error" : true, "message" : err.message} :
                {"error" : false, "message" : "Data added"}
            );
        });

    });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution as follows:

- Set port forwarding to my IP address (192.168.0.198:8143) on the router.
- Set static lease for the IP to my machine, to ensure the port forwarding continues to work.

Now my my external IP (xxx:8143) points forwards directly to my machines IP.

I would guess there is another solution that doesn't involve configuring my router, but I haven't found it.